# is modifying all database columns varchar2 size to be 4000 char, will affect the database or the storage?

Tags: oracle, table-structure

oracle database 19.20 c
the size of the column will be reserved for 4000 char immediately or it will reserve as much they need?

i tried to change all varchar2 columns of some table to be 4000 to avoid modifying the size later.

Comment: `varchar2` doesn't reserve space, `char` does. But agree with Littlefoot - it's very bad practice to make everything 4000. At a minimum it becomes difficult to query in SQLPlus and throws out the ability to index the columns. Instead, properly size your datatypes to your actual data. If width varies (e.g. 20-40 chars) go with something only slightly larger (50 chars). If it can't vary (SSN, or Y/N flag), make it exactly the correct width. Avoid `char` entirely. The more your data model fits your data the more self-descriptive it is and the fewer assumptions code or people make will be off.

Answer (score 3):

From my point of view, absolutely wrong approach. **Why** would all *strings* be stored into `(var)char(4000)`? (with `char` being even worse, as you'd reserve 4000 characters, fixed, with all values right-padded with spaces up to whole column length.)

First name - 4000 characters? Do you know anyone who has that long first name? Phone number? Sex?

Shortly: plan data model; think about data you're about to store; wisely choose datatypes (and their length).

As of program units you'll write: variables, that refer to columns, should *inherit* their datatype. For example:

```
No :  v_first_name varchar2(10);
Yes:  v_first_name employees.first_name%type
```

because if it turns out that you didn't guess it right initially, you'd just modify column length, but all procedures would *just work*, without you having to modify a single bit of code.